# How to explode a file extension from a filename that is in an array?

Tags: php

```
function addFlyer($db) {
if (isset($_FILES['file_array'])) {
    $name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
    $tmp_name_array = $_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'];
    $type_array = $_FILES['file_array']['type'];
    $size_array = $_FILES['file_array']['size'];
    $error_array = $_FILES['file_array']['error'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($tmp_name_array); $i++) {
        if (file_exists($name_array[$i])) {
            echo "Sorry file already exists. ";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name_array[$i], "images/" . $name_array[$i])) {
                echo $name_array[$i] . " upload is complete<br>";
            } else {
                echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for " . $name_array[$i] . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment I got this code for upload multiple files to a folder and insert it into the database (I excluded the code for inserting.)

But if I want to use the file_exists function correctly I need to seperate the extension and the name from the file. But I have no idea how I can explode an array.

Is there someone that can help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to explode or something else. You could get image extension by path_info() PHP Function. PLease have a look on below.

```
$path = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

If you want to explode a file name. You can use below trick

```
$file = $_FILES['file_array']['name']; 
$image_info = explode(".", $file); 
$image_type = end($image_info)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. The problem is, I want to use the function file_exists and that function sends the extension with it.. so it's not working normally.

Comment: If you want to explode a file name. You can use below trick

$file = $_FILES['file_array']['name'];
$image_info = explode(".", $file);
$image_type = end($image_info);

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($name_array as $value) {
if (file_exists($value)) {
    echo "Sorry file already exists. ";
    $uploadOk = 0;
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($value, "images/" . $value)) {
        echo $value . " upload is complete<br>";
    } else {
        echo "move_uploaded_file function failed for " . $value . "<br>";
    }
}
```

}

This may work. Use foreach() loop instead of for() loop.